# animate asp.net menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, menu, background-color

I found a javascript code that change the opacity of the asp.net menu items ,

```
  $(function () {
        $("ul.level1 li").hover(function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.7}, "slow");
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1}, "slow");
        });
    });
```

But I don't want to change the opacity !
How can I do if I want to change the items' background color by following this function ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $("ul.level1 li").hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: red}, "slow");
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: blue}, "slow");
    });
});
```

You will also need [this](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/)

A better method is to use simple css [transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) with the :hover pseudo selector.

**Update**

As I said there is no native support for background color animation in jQuery. You need to include the plugin if you want to do it in javascript.

Still, see how easy it is to make it with css [here](http://jsfiddle.net/slytael/ZNEAE/)

Comment: it's not `background-color`, use `backgroundColor` (camel case!) The css syntax is slightly different when used in JQuery... have a look here http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/jquery under 'Manipulation' then 'Style Manipulation' :)

Comment: @Slytael , +1 for your css example with `transition: all 2s;-webkit-transition: all 2s;` , it's work great :)